# небольшое размытие текста CSS

Tags: html, css

здравствуйте, есть набор анимаций для css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

когда я использую его на любом блоке своего сайта, текст внутри него принимает немного шершавую и точечную форму (эффект), как показано на скриншоте, с лева все нормально, с права то о чем я говорю. я понимаю что возможно вы скажите что это не заметно, но все таки это заметно и раздражает глаза, так вот я хотел бы узнать, как можно убрать этот эффект?

я порылся в интернете, и нашел css свойство которое способно добавить его  -`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` но свойство которое способно убрать это репение мне найти не удалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Air дело в том что код тут не причем, это дело в animate.css ибо он делает такой эффект абсолютно с любым текстом, даже на чистой странице

Comment: @Air такое происходит во время использования любой анимации

Comment: Без конкретного примера (вашего кода) вам никто не поможет